# JavaScript: How can I change the visibility of an element when clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a code that allows me to make click on any part of the screen and when I click the screen should display the message "click!" 
By far I got the next code

html:

```
<html>
    <head>
         <title>Sense events anywhere</title>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="anywhere.js"></script>
         <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="anywhere.css" />
    </head>
    <body id="body" onload="init();">
      <div id="message"> Click! </div>
  </body></html>
```

JavaScript:

```
var e;
function init(){
   e = document.getElementById("message");
   document.getElementById("message").style.visibility = "hidden";
   e.onmousedown = displayIt(e);
   e.onmouseup = hideIt;
}     
function displayIt(e) {
   e.style.visibility = "visible";
}
function hideIt() {
   e.style.visibility = "hidden";   
}
```

CSS:

```
body {  
}
div#message{
}
```

By far I only tried to turn the message visible and "invisible" when clicked but it doesn't work
Sorry for my English, I'm not a native speaker. If anyone could help me, that will be great.
Thanks.

Comment: You will need the click event here instead of the mouseevents. Do you have a jsfiddle set up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var visible = true,
body = document.getElementById("body"),
mess = document.getElementById("message");

body.onclick = function() {
     if (visible === true) {
        mess.style.visibility = "hidden";
        visible = false;
} else {
        mess.style.visibility = "visible";
        visible = true;
       }
}
```

**Edit** Replaced body in selector as i didnt notice you wanted any part of the screen clicked

Answer (score 0):

Solution with jQuery (I recommend you to use display property. Because, if you use visibility, element will keep its space even it is hidden. With display: none; element is "removed".):

**HTML**

```
<div id="message"> Click! </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#message {
   display: none;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).click(function(){
        $('#message').toggle();
    });
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/j3KVT/2/

---

If you want to use visibility property then this is (one of many) solution with jQuery:

**HTML**

```
<div id="message">Click!</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#message').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $(window).click(function () {

        if ($('#message').css('visibility') == 'hidden') 
        $('#message').css('visibility', 'visible');

        else $('#message').css('visibility', 'hidden');

    });
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/j3KVT/3/

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
function toggleMessage(targetID){
    var target = document.getElementById(targetID),
        display = target.style.display;
    target.style.display = display && display == 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
}

document.body.addEventListener('click', function(){
    toggleMessage('message');
});
```

[Simple JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/peN4t/2/).

Amended the above to use `visibility` (rather than `display`):

```
function toggleMessage(targetID){
    var target = document.getElementById(targetID),
        visibility = target.style.visibility;
    target.style.visibility = visibility && visibility == 'visible' ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
}

document.body.addEventListener('click', function(){
    toggleMessage('message');
});
```

[Simple JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/peN4t/1/).

References:

- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).